# NVIDIA nvcc compilation flag for constexpr depth and IEEE 754 exponent computation

Tags: c++11, cuda, constexpr, ieee-754, nvcc

Consider the following code that computes the exponent of a double floating point number as a constant expression (in the format specified by the IEEE 754 standard).

```
    template <typename T>  constexpr T abs_CE(const T x){return x>=0?x:-x;}
    constexpr unsigned long long int __double_exponent_CE_(const double x){return x==0?0:(x>=2.?(__double_exponent_CE_(x/2.)+1):(x<1?__double_exponent_CE_(x*2.)-1:0));}
    constexpr unsigned long long int __double_exponent_CE(const double x){return (x==0)?0:(__double_exponent_CE_(abs_CE(x))+1023);}
```

That code fails to compile as constant expression in gcc under normal compilation flags circumstances for certain inputs like std::numeric_limits< double >::max. The reason it fails to compile is because it  exceeds the max recursion depth for a constant expression (512 is the default value). For example std::numeric_limits< double >::max requires 1024 calls, exceeding the limit.

If the flag -fconstexpr-depth=2048 is added, then the code compiles perfectly, and evaluates to a constant expression that can be passed as a template parameter.

That code fails to compile under nvcc with the flag `-Xcompiler -fconstexpr-depth=2048` (specifically it crashes when nvcc issues the cicc command), so is there any way to change the depth limit in nvcc? I have not found any flag to change it in [NVCC options](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options).

Just in case there is no such equivalent flag in nvcc, does anybody know any other way to compute the exponent of a double in compile time with less than 512 recursions calls?

Comment: C++14 allows iteration in `constexpr` functions. This can avoid the recursion depth issue.

Comment: Your code as posted compiles cleanly for me on CUDA 10 with `nvcc -std=c++11 t400.cu`, centOS 7, gcc 4.8.5

Comment: @RobertCrovella does the code compile when you pass the result as a as a template parameter, with the input std::numeric_limits<double>::max?

Comment: like fun<__double_exponent_CE(std::numeric_limits<double>::max>() ?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using "[--expt-relaxed-constexpr](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options)" flag:

> Experimental flag:
>
> Allow host code to invoke `__device__constexpr` functions, and device code to invoke `__host__constexpr` functions.
>
> Note that the behavior of this flag may change in future compiler releases.

Also in [CUDA C Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constexpr-functions) :

> By default, a constexpr function cannot be called from a function with incompatible execution space. The experimental nvcc flag `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` removes this restriction. When this flag is specified, host code can invoke a  `__device__ constexpr` function and device code can invoke a `__host__ constexpr` function.